# send email with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, email

i need to send an email with the below query but cannot get it to send? what am i doing wrong? i have removed the connect details. i just get a HTTP ERROR 500

````
require "defaultincludes.inc";

   $to_email = "antham1616@gmail.com";
   $subject = "Tomorrow Jobs";
   $body = "$sql =

   Select * From mrbs_entry Where from_unixtime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND driver = 'Kim Emery' ORDER by start_time asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<br> <strong>Bus:</strong> ".$row["room_id"]. "  Driver: ".$row["driver"]. "   Trip: ".$row["name"] . " Fee: ".$row["fee"] . " <tr>";
        {echo "<br> Time: " . $row["pickup_time"]. " Name: ". $row["pickup_address"]. " Going: ". $row["pickup_1_going"]. "<br>";}
         }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo "<img src='images/bus checks.jpg' alt='checks' />";

   $headers = "From: office@ndct.co.uk";

   if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
      echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
   } else {
      echo("Email sending failed...");
   }
?>```
````

Comment: `$result = $conn->query($sql);`: The variable `$sql` is not defined, which probably causes your 500 error.

Comment: For body 'test body' is this code working properly?

Comment: managed to get it to send an email but just shows the actual code not the result   $body = $sql = "Select * From mrbs_entry Where from_unixtime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY AND driver = 'driver1' ORDER by start_time asc";

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a syntax error somewhere in your code. Have a look in the error log.

This like looks weird:

```
$body = "$sql =
```